# React Native: Getting data from Firebase

Tags: react-native

I'm simply trying to retrieve data from the database in Firebase, and here's what I've got

```
var userList = [];
    
    firebase.database()
  .ref('/users/')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      
      userList.push(doc.val());
      
    });
    
  });
  
  console.log(userList);
```

Even though I copy and pasted this code from a tutorial, the userList is empty outside of the snapshot. Can you tell me why that is?

Comment: Are you using the React Native Firebase library? https://rnfirebase.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request to firebase is asynchronous so `console.log(userList);` is called before `userList.push(doc.val());` gets called.

You should make `userList` a component state variable so that when you update it your component will re render.

Something like the following should work:

```
class UserListComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userList: [],
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() { 
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/users/')
      .once('value')
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          this.setState({
            userList: [...this.state.userList, doc.val()],
          });
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.userList.map((item) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```